# Multi-Stage Voting Game in zTree

Tags: behavioral-economics, experimental-economics

For a project that I am doing, I need to code up a mulit-stage voting game in zTree. I have never used the program before but I am slowly teaching myself through watching videos and reading manuals. My question is: does anyone have an example of a voting game where players are eliminated each round that they have already coded in zTree. Or, is there some place to go that has archived zTree codes which I could access?